# Is the phrase 'offer her a home' an idiom?

Tags: vocabulary

The following sentence is taken from a novel. In the sentence, is the phrase 'offer her a home'  an idiom?

> He was unable to offer her a home.

Comment: What do you understand by "an idiom"? Your example involves the normal meanings of ***offer*** (make available to someone) and ***home*** (one's normal place of residence, the place where one lives), so it doesn't fit the standard definition of [***idiom***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/idiom) as *A group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words.*

Answer (score 2):

To "offer someone a home" is to give them a place to live, to take them in, not  to give them a house as their very own.

It can also mean to give a person a place to pursue their career, to hire them, for example, onto a university faculty.

> His aunt and uncle offered him a home after his explorer parents
>   disappeared into the jungle and never came out.
>
> He was grateful to the University of ________  for offering him a home when he was fresh out of graduate school.